# Understanding jsonify() function. Maybe it's used for displaying the contacts?

Tags: python, json, function, class, oop

I have to build, in python, an address book of contacts using a json file. So, I have to define a class Contact which has as attributes hust the name, surname and mail. In the solution there is a function that I never would have thought of: jsonify(self). I don't understand what it does and why I need it. Someone can help me figure it out?

```
def jsonify(self):
    contact = {'name':self.name,'surname':self.surname,'mail':self.mail}
    return contact
```

Comment: One thing it does is lying. It does not "jsonifies", it "dictifies"

Comment: On a more serious note, it builds a dictionary from (some of?) the instance's attributes and returns it

Comment: Did you try to call it and print what it returns?

Comment: I'm not following. It's just the solution the professor gave to us without explaination, so I don't get what you mean. Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `json` library, you can convert objects into JSON really easily, but it needs to know how to go about converting them. The library doesn't know how to interpret your custom class:

```
>>> import json
>>> contact = Contact("Hello", "World", "hello@world.com")
>>> contact_json = json.dumps(contact)
TypeError: Object of type 'Contact' is not JSON serializable
```

*(`json.dumps(obj)` converts its input to JSON and returns it as a string. You can also do `json.dump(obj, file_handle)` to save it to a file).*

A dictionary is a known type in Python, so the `json` library knows how to convert it into `json` format:

```
>>> import json
>>> contact = Contact("Hello", "World", "hello@world.com")
>>> contact_json = json.dumps(contact.jsonify())

{
  "name": "Hello",
  "surname": "World",
  "mail": "hello@world.com"
}
```

Using that `jsonify` method, you're converting the fields from your class into something that the `json` library can understand and knows how to translate.

This is a quick and easy way to serialise your object into JSON, but isn't necessarily the best way to do it - ideally you'd tell the JSON library how to interpret your class (see this related question: [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)).

**Edit:** Seeing the comment discussion - I'm assuming here you have an understanding of Python data structures and classes. If this is not the case it's worth reading up on those first.

Comment: Your answer has been really helpful and it's very clear to a beginner like me. Thank you! So should I use this kind of function whenever I need to work with json files that "contains" classes?

Comment: No problem. Yes, if you have an object, which is from a custom class, and you want to store it into a JSON file, you'll need either something like this, or ideally, something like the `JSONEncoder` example I linked above. The advantage of the latter is that it's a lot more flexible than manually crafting a dictionary, but I suspect your professor gave you this example as it's easier to follow.